# How to get sum of nodes of a tree which has children in a list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

So I have a Tree which is like this:

```
class Tree{
public:
int data1;
string data2;
Animal animal;
std::list<Tree> children;
};
```

I am trying to calculate sum of `data1` nodes at odd level, but I am not able to do so. I calculated sum of all nodes like this:

```
int addData1(const Tree* t, int sum){
    if(t == nullptr) {
        return sum;
    }
    else{
        int temp = 0;
        std::list<Tree> forest = t->children;
        std::list<Tree>::iterator it;

        for(it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it){
            Tree curr = *it;
            temp += addData1(&curr, sum);
        }

        return t->data1 + temp;
    }
}
```

But I am unable to do so for odd levels, I tried it like this, but I get incorrect sum:

```
int addData1Odd(const Tree* t, bool odd, int sum){
    if(t == nullptr){
        return sum;
    }
    else{
        int temp = 0;
        std::list<Tree> forest = t->children;
        std::list<Tree>::iterator it;

        for(it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it){
            Tree curr = *it;
            if(odd)
                temp += addData1Odd(&curr, !odd, sum);
        }

        return t->data1 + temp;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: While it could be a hassle with recursive code, have you tried to step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried that too, but it's very confusing and I am assuming something is wrong with the way I am thinking about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stop recursing if you are not on an odd level. You should still recurse, but not add it to your sum

Edit:
Try this:

```
    for(it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it){
        Tree curr = *it;
        temp += addData1Odd(&curr, !odd, sum);
    }

    if (odd)
       return t->data1 + temp;
    else
       return temp;
```

Comment: I think that's what I also tried in my implementation but it's not working.

Comment: Hi Panda, I've updated my answer with a code example

Comment: Also note that you can use range-based for loop here, which is less prone to errors. For more information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for